# How to add image and button in one border or box?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I want to add an image and a button in one box.

I want the *image at the top and the button underneath the image*. I want both of them inside one solid border.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the re-phrase your question.

Comment: When posting questions in SO, allow us to help you by helping us by providing code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might get you started:

```html
<div id="myBox" style="width:200px;padding:10px;text-align:center;border:2px solid purple;">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/150" /><br>
    <button>Click Me</button>
</div>
```

---

Note that we usually separate the styling (`style=`) from the HTML:

```
<style>
    #myBox {width:200px;padding:10px;text-align:center;border:2px solid purple;}
</style>
<div id="myBox">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/150" /><br>
    <button>Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the below snippet to get the desired effect *(**Note**: this is just a sample to illustrate how one can add image and text below using HTML and CSS, on clicking the button, it won't redirect or perform any action)*:

**HTML:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary tweetButton">
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/twitter-128.png" width="20" height="20" />
    <p>Tweet</p>
</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tweetButton {
  width: 90px;
}

.tweetButton p {
  margin: 0 0 2px;
}
```

Check out the demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/vxabort7/).